# SPFile.OpenBinary throwing error "Cannot open file"

Tags: development, spfile

I have the chunk of code below:

```
SPListItem source = //some list item;
foreach (string file in source.Attachments)
{
    SPFile oFile = source.Web.GetFile(file);
    string strFilename = oFile.Name;
    byte[] binFile = oFile.OpenBinary();  //Errors out here!
    destination.Attachments.Add(oFile.Name, binFile);
    destination.SystemUpdate();
}
```

Which throws this error:

> EXCEPTION in CrossSiteCopy!  Cannot open file "2012-05-21_104000.png".
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException
>   comEx)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAsStream(String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Boolean bHonorLevel, Byte iLevel,
>   OpenBinaryFlags grfob, String bstrEtagNotMatch, String& pEtagNew,
>   String& pContentTagNew)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.GetFileStreamCore(OpenBinaryFlags
>   openOptions, String etagNotMatch, String& etagNew, String&
>   contentTagNew)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.GetFileStream(OpenBinaryFlags openOptions,
>   String etagNotMatch, String& etagNew, String& contentTagNew)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.OpenBinary(SPOpenBinaryOptions
>   openOptions)      at
>   Copy_Special.CrossSiteCopy.CopyFieldValues(SPListItem source,
>   SPListItem destination)      at
>   Copy_Special.CrossSiteCopy.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0()      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_2()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback
>   secureCode, Object param)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)      at
>   Copy_Special.CrossSiteCopy.Execute(ActivityExecutionContext
>   executionContext)

It's not giving me much information about WHY it cannot open the file.  Can any one point me to what the problem might be?

Comment: Can you check the SP log? Also, Can you make sure the source exists (wherever the file is)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify more than just the attachment file name in the SPWeb.GetFile method! Specify the Web relative file URL or the server relative file URL here. You can construct the Web relative file URL from source.Attachments.UrlPrefix + file

Comment: Instead of just using + to combine URLs you should use SPUrlUtility.CombineUrls

Comment: Thx was not aware of this util method! Anyway, I agree and am also using my own util Url.Combine that is not so SharePoint specific. It also takes any number of string inputs for combination.